# In Windows 7, how should I set up duplicate dual monitor configurations?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, switchable-graphics

I'm fixing to set up my home office once we've cleared (most of) the junk out of it. I already have a non-adjustable standing desk and I'd like to put a sitting desk right next to it so I can take breaks from standing and keep working. I'm thinking I'll keep the laptop on the sitting desk next to a spare monitor, and two monitors up on the standing desk, and move a wireless keyboard/mouse combo with me when I switch. How do I set it up so that the two "upstairs" displays are the only active ones when I'm standing, and the two downstairs are the only active ones when I'm seated? Is there a monitor switcher that is designed for this?

I know I can get an adjustable desk but they cost way more than just the extra few monitors I'd have to get for what I have in mind.

Comment: Adjustable desks actually aren't that bad ...geek desk is about $800, so if you're using expensive monitors, it may be worth it. We have 3 of those at our office for developers.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look at http://www.ergotron.com/tabid/65/PRDID/378/language/en-US/default.aspx It is a monitor/keyboard stand that adjusts.  They just started using these at work recently and seem to be quite liked by the 6-8 people who I have talked to that have them.

It may be possible to get a dual port kvm like [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Port-Monitor-Switch-Audio/dp/B00310EES0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00310EES0) but you would have to ask the manufacturer if going the other way would work or not. If its a mechanical switch type it shouldn't matter but most are electronic now so only the manufacturer would be able to garontee one way or another.

You may be able to get a autohotkey script set up to switch between monitors if you have enough connections on the pc.  some laptops can have 3 or 4 displays recognized by using a docking station but only 2 active due to gpu restrictions.